# Is it even possible to run a Linux docker image on windows server 2019 (VMware)?

Tags: docker, windows-server-2019

Now I been evaluation, trying and testing this for many hours and the frustration start to eat me up.

Due to company policies I have nothing else to play with than a host based on WMware. On that i tried to nest a Hyper-V role. The Hyper-V appear in the server manager so in some way I must succeded. From here I cant perform anything similar to the instructions given in the many blogposts and instructions I read. The instructione on how to proceed are very ambivalent and in many cases inaccurate. Is there a way forward or should I just forget all about it, because there are no way that I will be successfull in achiving linux docker images on windows server 2019. Worth mentioning is that windows docker images runs like a charm on the server when I have the docker version for windows containers.

I have installed Docker EE Preview so you don't have to ask that. Basically I followed all instructions given when I google "run linux containers on windows server 2019"

Is there anyone out there that managed to perform this task with similar setup?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57691939/1031534 and tell if this provides you with a usable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, the situation is practically the same.

I have a *Windows Server 2019 Standard Edition* installed in virtual machine on *VMware* platform on host server.

Since *Docker* needs *Hyper-V* for running internal virtual machine, there is an issue of nested virtualization to deal with (*VMware* on host, and *Hyper-V* on guest).

This issue can be resolved according to instructions presented on address:
https://doitfixit.com/blog/2014/03/06/qhyper-v-components-is-not-runningq-nested-in-vmware-workstation/

Apart from settings for enabling nested virtualization in *VMware* program, there was a need to manually edit **.vmx** file, and more specifically to include the following properties in it:

```
hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = "FALSE"
guestOS = "winhyperv"
```

Then, I've finally found a working combination of *Windows Server* and *Docker* that can effectively run with *Linux* containers, by installing an edge release of *Docker Desktop Community 2.1.3.0* published on 2019-09-16.

This release (as well as other edge releases of *Docker*) is available at address: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/edge-release-notes/